# Get multiple users with meta value in one query and populate WP_User class

Tags: wp-query, query, users

Hopefully someone can help me with this.

When you load multiple users with `get_users()` *(let's say 100+)* WP triggers the user meta query for every single user.
This triggers 101 queries (main user query + meta query for each user).

The thing is, I only need 1 meta value from the database (capabilities for the current blog) and I see that the WP_User class doesn't use any of the other data for role and capability management.

I already have the SQL ready, no problemo. But does anyone know how to populate the WP_User class while bypassing the default meta query?

*(Off course this will need to be compatible with any stuff that happens afterwards by other plugins)*

See `wp-includes/class-wp-user.php`

Default callstack for WP_User (when passing a `$wpdb->get_results()` user object):

```
WP_User->_construct
WP_User->init()
WP_User->for_blog()
WP_User->_init_caps()
    - get_user_meta()
        - update_meta_cach()
            - query :-(
```

For completeness, my current SQL:

```
SELECT {$wpdb->users}.*, {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->users} 
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} ON {$wpdb->users}.ID = {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id
WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = '{$wpdb->get_blog_prefix()}capabilities'
ORDER BY {$wpdb->users}.display_name
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just so I get what you're on about...so if I have 30 users and on every one of them I have a `meta_query` argument + a certain `meta_value`, does that mean WordPress performs 30 queries? Or 60? I didn't get it with the 100+ and 101, but I'm really curious because THAT much fewer database queries is gooood..! Because I thought it was just one query saved to a variable and then it's just "local iteration"

Comment: Very late reply (didn't return here since I've figured it out). But yes, after testing back then I found that if you query multiple users WP adds a separate query for each user to get the metadata. Might be that this is fixed since then, I'll have to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested.

Got it solved using the `get_user_metadata` filter to short circuit the metaquery and cache loading.

**Steps:**

- Run query
- Store result data in the class property
- Add `get_user_metadata` filter
- Start `foreach` loop on results
- Trigger `new WP_User( $result_value )` for each result
- Within the filter function, validate meta key on `$wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'capabilities'`.
- Return the unserialized value from the capabilities meta data
- After the loop, remove the `get_user_metadata` filter again
- Done!

**Full query (slightly modified)**

```
SELECT {$wpdb->users}.*, {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value as roles FROM {$wpdb->users} 
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} ON {$wpdb->users}.ID = {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id
WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = '{$wpdb->get_blog_prefix()}capabilities'
ORDER BY {$wpdb->users}.display_name
```

This will return all the values from the users table + an extra column named `roles` with the meta_value for `TABLEPREFIX_capabilities`

There, one single query to load a bulk of users and their capabilities/roles.